How to use AdvancedResponseWriter with new signature
I was using AdvancedResponseWriter as shown in code below in order to save incoming stream in file. But in the new version of RestSharp the method changed it's signature to get Func <HttpResponseMessage message, RestRequest request, RestResponse restResponse>
How should I change my code in order to use new signature?
string fileName = ...;
Uri url = ...;

var restRequest = new RestRequest
{
    Method = Method.Get,
    AdvancedResponseWriter = (Stream data, IHttpResponse http) =>
    {
        var contentType = http.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType.Equals(OctetStreamContentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            contentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(GetFileName(fileName, url, OctetStreamContentType));
        }

        filePath = this.fileSystem.Path.Combine(this.fileSystem.Path.GetTempPath(), $"{connectorId}", GetFileName(fileName, url, contentType));
        this.fileSystem.Directory.CreateDirectory(this.fileSystem.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

        var copySuccess = false;
        using (var file = this.fileSystem.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            copySuccess = data.CopyToWithLimit(file, sizeLimit); // copies the data stream to file stream 
        }

        if (!copySuccess)
        {
            ...
        }
    },
}
.AddHeader(AcceptHeader, AcceptHeaderValue);


Why don't you use DownloadStreamAsync instead?

@AlexeyZimarev Can you please advise how to access RestResponse in this case? I need to grab content-type and status code.

You're right, it is not possible. A better way to deal with downloads is planned but not implemented, there's some complexity involved. If you want to use the advanced response writer, you can get both content type and status code from the response message.
